# With the parsedatetime library in Python, is it possible to restrict a date to the current year?

Tags: python, parsing

Using [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime), I'd like to pass a value like `Jan 1` to the calendar parser and have it return Jan 1st of the **current year** (which, as I post this, would be `2014-01-01`).

By default, parsedatetime returns the *next* occurrence of the date (i.e. `2015-01-01`):

```
>>> import parsedatetime as pdt
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from time import mktime
>>> cal = pdt.Calendar()
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 1, 15, 41, 7, 486294)
>>> str(datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(cal.parse('Jan 1')[0])))
'2015-01-01 14:41:13'
>>> str(datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(cal.parse('Dec 31')[0])))
'2014-12-31 14:41:17'
```

I've tried inputs like `last Jan 1` and `Jan 1 this year` without success.

Is there a way to tell the parser to return the current year's value?

---

Editing to add a couple requirements that weren't specified with original question:

- Supports natural language processing (that's why I'm using parsedatetime)
- Doesn't compromise other parsedatetime parsing functionality (like years other than current and values like `yesterday` and `6 months before 3/1`)

Comment: Do you still need the ability to specify a year different than the current one? Otherwise you could just `replace` the year.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, it needs to support more than just current year. I suppose it could use a magic value like 1900 or something. Still, I'm not even sure that would work in this case as this is being integrated within another DSL-driven parser. I'll have to check this out.

Comment: I actually get 2014 on linux

Comment: @PadraicCunningham For calendar dates in the past? Double check my example. (My example was run on Debian.)

Comment: just had a proper look, it does  show `2014` but it is `2014-12-31` so even stranger output.

Comment: must be timezone difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parse` function appears to take a `sourceTime` parameter that you can set to the 1st of the current year.

See https://bear.im/code/parsedatetime/docs/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Bear here - have no idea how to get my original SO profile back as I used to use ClaimID...

anywho - you can set a flag to cause parsedatetime to never go forward a year when parsing only month/day values...

```
import parsedatetime as pdt
ptc = pdt.Constants()
ptc.YearParseStyle = 0

cal = pdt.Calendar(ptc)
print cal.parse('Jan 1')
# ((2014, 1, 1, 15, 57, 32, 5, 214, 1), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. This simplified my implementation, which I incorporated into my answer. I hope you're able to recover your account. Good luck!

Comment: By the way, is there any documentation available on constants?

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the year on your datetime object. For example :

```
str(datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(cal.parse('Dec 31')[0])))
```

would become:

```
str(datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(cal.parse('Dec 31')[0])).replace(year=datetime.today().year))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't tied to using that library (and maybe you are?) you could do it like this:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().replace(month=1, day=1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
'2014-01-01 22:55:56'
>>>
```

Comment: Not necessarily tied to the library but I am looking for something that handles natural language parsing and parsedatetime seems like it is the most widely used.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, datetime

d = datetime.strptime('Jan 1', '%b %d')
d = date(datetime.now().year, d.month, d.day)
```

gives `datetime.date(2014, 1, 1)` for `d`, which you can then format with

```
print d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

2014-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

An improved implementation based on [Bear's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098991/1093087).

Again this is constrained by the fact that, since this is being implemented within another DSL parser, `natural_date` can only accept a single string:

```
import parsedatetime as pdt
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from time import mktime


def natural_date(human_readable):
    human_readable = human_readable.lower()

    # Flag to cause parsedatetime to never go forward
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/25098991/1093087
    ptc = pdt.Constants()
    ptc.YearParseStyle = 0
    cal = pdt.Calendar(ptc)

    result, parsed_as = cal.parse(human_readable)

    if not parsed_as:
        raise ValueError("Unable to parse %s" % (human_readable))

    return date.fromtimestamp(mktime(result))


def test_natural_date():
    cases = [
        # input, expect
        ('jan 1', date(date.today().year, 1, 1)),
        ('dec 31', date(date.today().year, 12, 31)),
        ('yesterday', date.today() - timedelta(days=1)),
        ('3 months before 12/31', date(date.today().year, 9, 30))
    ]

    for human_readable, expect in cases:
        result = natural_date(human_readable)
        print("%s -> %s" % (human_readable, result))
        assert result == expect, human_readable


test_natural_date()
```

---

Credit also goes to Mark Ransom, who [unearthed `sourceTime` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25090036/1093087), which provided another way to solve this issue, although that solution was complicated by [this issue](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime/issues/38).